# What are the proper and complete steps to deploy a .NET application from Visual Studio for public use?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment

I usually write C# programs for myself, or just parts of other applications.  Now, I have been working on a project that I would like to eventually commercialize and I am interested in the easiest way to deploy a simple application from VS 2008 that will primarily be downloaded and installed.  I am not just interested in installer choices, but build options, exception handling settings, and any other essential details.

The documentation on MSDN is a little overwhelming.  Just the section on deployment how-to's has over 100 topics!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184415.aspx

What should I focus on and in what order?  Does anyone have a personal checklist that they run through just to make sure all of the bases are covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get your licensing mechanism figured out. Serial numbers, activation, whatever. **Test it**.
2. Build your assemblies and obfuscate them. If the assemblies are small, I'd actually `ILMerge` them too - makes the whole thing more manageable.
3. Make an installer. ClickOnce **is** an option, albeit for the brave. Its major feature is that it self-updates. Which is problematic if you want to charge money for updates. I'd just use WiX and code self-updating myself - not exactly hard.

Answer (score 1):

For that scenario I'd avoid clickonce, so [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd.aspx) seems to be the most relevant for deployment.

In terms of complier options, the standard Release build should be good enough; you might want to consider a code obfuscation tool, depending on how good a lawyer you can afford if people decide to reverse engineer your code...